# Find an invertible matrix $Q \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Let be  \begin{align} A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 1 & 0\\  1 &
>  1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in M_3(\mathbb{R}) \end{align}
>
> **a)** Find the minimal polynomial of $A$
>
> **b)** Determine if $A$ is diagonizable over $\mathbb{R}$
>
> **c)** Find an invertible matrix $Q \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a upper triangular matrix

**My attempt:**

**a)** First we find the characteristic polynomial
\begin{align}
det (A-tI)=(1-t)^{3}
\end{align}
Then, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(1-t)$

**b)** To verify if $A$ is diagonalizable, we have to verify if the dimension of the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue 1, is 3. That is, to check if the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue 1.

\begin{align} \begin{pmatrix} 1-1 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 1-1 & 0\\  1 &
 1 & 1-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\z\end{pmatrix}&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 0\\  1 &
 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix} \\ \end{align}

\begin{align}
\Longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

$\Longrightarrow$ The dimension of the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue 1, is zero. Then, $A$ is not diagonalizable.

**My doubts:**

- Am I correct in **a)** and **b)**?
- How can I find the matrix of **c)**? I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

For $(a)$, it's easy to check by inspection that your minimal polynomial is not correct.

---

For $(b)$, an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$ must satisfy $Av = v$, or $(A-I)v = 0$ as you put it.
If $v = (x,y,z)$ then $(A-I)v = (y, 0, x+y)$, so $(A-I)v = 0$ implies $y = 0$ which then implies $x+y = x = 0$.
Notice that this leaves $z$ free, and indeed it's easy to see $(0,0,1)$ is an eigenvector.

Of course, that still means $A$ is not diagonalizable.

---

For $(c)$, if $A$ were diagonalizable, say $A = QDQ^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, then you could write $D = Q^{-1}AQ$ and since $D$ is diagonal it is also upper triangular.

Now, you've shown in $(b)$ that $A$ is not diagonalizable, but every matrix has a certain normal form that one could say is the next best thing.
Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much! But one little question, why is the minimal polynomial wrong? The characteristic polynomial is correct, and as the unique root is 1, then I thought that the minimal polynomial must be just $(1-t)$. So, how can I find it?

Comment: You could find it by inspection. The minimal polynomial $m$ satisfies $m(A) = 0$, and it also divides the characteristic polynomial $p$. Since the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)^3$, your options are limited to $(\lambda - 1)$, $(\lambda - 1)^2$ and $(\lambda - 1)^3$. You can check manually which of them (starting from lowest degree) first vanishes when you plug in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You got the right characteristic polynomial. But the dimension of the eigenspace associated with an eigenvalue is *always* greater than $0$. In this case, it is $1$: that eigenspace is spanned by $(0,0,1)$. So, let $e_1=(0,0,1)$. Now, you can check that a solution of $A.(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)+e_1$ is $(1,0,0)$. So, let $e_2=(1,0,0)$. And you can check that a solution of $A.(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)+e_2$ is $(-1,1,0)$. So, let$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $Q$ are $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$), and$$Q^{-1}.A.Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you very very much! Just one question, why did you find by that way $e_2$ and $e_3$? I mean, how did you know that the solution of those system were the vectors that we needed to construct the matrix $Q$?

Comment: Since the only eigenvalue is $1$ and since there is only one eigenvector $e_1$ with that eigenvalue (up to multiplicity), I knew that the Jordan narmal form of $A$ would be$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$But this means that there is a vector $e_1$ such that $A.e_2=e_1+e_2$ and that there is a vector $e_3$ such that $A.e_3=e_3+e_2$.